# Python 2.7: Printing out an decoded string

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, character-encoding, character

I have an file that is called: Abrázame.txt

I want to decode this so that python understands what this 'á' char is so that it will print me Abrázame.txt

This is the following code i have on an Scratch file:

```
import os

s = os.path.join(r'C:\Test\AutoTest', os.listdir(r'C:\\Test\\AutoTest')[0])
print(unicode(s.decode(encoding='utf-16', errors='strict')))
```

The error i get from above is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/naythan_onfri/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(unicode(s.decode(encoding='utf-16', errors='strict')))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_16.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x74 in position 28: truncated data
```

I have looked up the utf-16 character set and it does indeed have 'á' character in it. So why is it that this string cannot be decoded with Utf-16.

Also i know that 'latin-1' will work and produce the string im looking for however since this is for an automation project and i wanting to ensure that any filename with any registered character can be decoded and used for other things within the project for example:

"Opening up file explorer at the directory of the file with the file already selected."

Is looping through each of the codecs(Mind you i believe there is 93 codecs) to find whichever one can decode the string, the best way of getting the result I'm looking for? I figure there something far better than that solution.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use python 2.x for this project? Python 3 is a much better choice.

Comment: You may have more luck with `encoding=sys.getfilesystemencoding()`

Comment: @tdelaney need to use python 2.7 as the current project infrastructure is using 2.7

Comment: @tdelaney, you sir have answered the question, made that change and i am getting the expected correct string I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to decode at the edge when you first read a string so that you don't have surprises later in your code. At the edge, you have some reasonable chance of guessing what that encoding is. For this code, the edge is

```
os.listdir(r'C:\\Test\\AutoTest')[0]
```

and you can get the current file system directory encoding. So,

```
import sys
fs_encoding = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
s = os.path.join(r'C:\Test\AutoTest',
    os.listdir(r'C:\\Test\\AutoTest')[0].decode(encoding=fs_encodig, errors='strict')
print(s)
```

Note that once you decode you have a unicode string and you don't need to build a new `unicode()` object from it.

`latin-1` works if that's your current code page. Its an interesting curiosity that even though Windows has supported "wide" characters with "W" versions of their API for many years, python 2 is single-byte character based and doesn't use them.

Long live python 3.

Comment: Don't use bytes paths in Windows prior to Python 3.6. `os.listdir` in Python 2 calls wide-character `FindFirstFileW` if you pass it a `unicode` path, which is all you should be using in Windows. Note that backslash should not be doubled in a [r]aw string. However Python 2's raw `unicode` literals are broken since they always process `\u` and `\U` escapes, i.e. you can't use `ur"C:\Users"` in Python 2. So either use forward slash or, when backslash is required, either double the backslash in a normal (not raw) string literal, or normalize the path to use backslash via `os.path.normpath`.